# Ending a SP 2013 Workflow Task Process after Rejection

Tags: designer, workflow2013

I am using a task process within a SharePoint 2013 workflow. I have an IF/ELSE statement setup for the task being approved or rejected; however it still continues to Stage 2, despite the outcome. Is there a way to end the workflow after the first rejection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `Transition to Stage` make a new if condition to check the value of the outcome variable as the following.

```
If Variable: Outcome equals Rejected
    Go to End of Workflow
Else
    Go to Stage 2
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have a "End workflow" action. It is only available in the transition to stage area.

Comment: you are right I have updated my answer

Comment: I can't use anything but "Go-to" actions in the Transaction to Stage area.

Comment: select go to action then right click >  select delete action, now in transition section, there is no anything , so just perform right click to add if condition, please if you can't do it tell me to post detail steps with image in my answer

Answer (score 1):

That should be in the transition. There should be a variable that was generated called Outcome the transition (if not you can set the variable after it gets completed) should have:

```
If(Outcome equals "Rejected")
  Go to "End of Workflow"
```

Comment: I'm not able to enter "Go to" as an action. Not in 2013.

Comment: should be under the "Transition to stage" bar.  Like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yyQYJ77zK0Q/UA8KhsJ-fpI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/Ju2thJeAYjY/s640/SP2013Stages.png

Unless you are saying SharePoint 2013, but using a SharePoint 2010 engine workflow...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I had to completely remove any current "go-to" statement from the Transition to Stage phase, save and refresh. Then I was able to insert the IF/ELSE statement. I'm not sure if that last part is absolutely necessary for everyone, but it worked for me.